# Maven dependency for javax.persistence.*: hibernate-jpa-2.1-api or javaee-api?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

The story is about maven project dependencies. I have:

- my project depends on ***hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final*** artifact which depends on
  ***hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final***
- and my project depends on ***javaee-api:7.0***
- ***hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final*** contains javax.persistence.* classes
- the same javax.persistence.* classes are contained in ***javaee-api:7.0***

Which dependency should i use in my project and with wich scope? If i leave both dependencies in final build then i will get a class-conflict.
It is desirable that the application can be deployed to any JavaEE container such as Glassfish, Wildfly, JBOSS, etc.

Note that ***hibernate-jpa-2.1-api*** is not specific api for any JavaEE server and is not implementation. It is just API compile-scope dependency of ***hibernate-core*** artifact. And i don't include this dependency manually, if i choose Hibernate as JPA implementation then ***hibernate-jpa-2.1-api*** will be included in build by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems i figured it out.

Most of the sources (for example http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/the_only_one_dependency_you) i learned stating that javaee-api dependency should be used only in provided scope. It's because the server implements these API's and implementations can vary. And you should never put *javaee-api.jar* in war or ear.

Also, wildfly server contains in standard modules set: *hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar*. Which means that in this partical javaee container *javax.persistence.** classes are provided by this library not *javaee-api.jar*.